# remove https from unsecure pages

Tags: https, http-request

We are using following configuration for adding https to our site.

[image]

**System > Configuration> Web> secure>**

**Use Secure URLs in Frontend : YES**

**Use Secure URLs in admin    : YES**

it added https to my account , customer login pages.

but from the above pages. if we click on any other catalog and product pages,

than also its adding https to category and product pages.

we have to remove https from these category and product pages. how we can do this ?

Suppose we are in **https** page. from this page, if we click on any pages, it will redirect to **https**. but from **http** page, if we click on any pages, it will redirect to **http** page only.

**.htaccess file**

```
# MAINTENANCE-PAGE REDIRECT
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine on
# RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^106\.51\.233\.96
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
# RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
#</IfModule>


#disable directory browsing

Options -Indexes

############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 512M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>



<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Comment: It shouldn't be happening in a default Magento installation, check if you have any such rule in .htaccess file.

Comment: @Prateek please check edited question. i posted .htaccess code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399485/redirect-https-to-http-on-non-secure-magento-pages

app/code/core/Mage/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php::_checkShouldBeSecure()

I amended this function (created copy in app/code/local add amended it there) adding in the elseif part

```
protected function _checkShouldBeSecure($request, $path='')
{
    if (!Mage::isInstalled() || $request->getPost()) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->_shouldBeSecure($path) && !Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()) {
        $url = $this->_getCurrentSecureUrl($request);

        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect($url)
            ->sendResponse();
        exit;
    } elseif (!$this->_shouldBeSecure($path) && Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()) {
        $url = $this->_getCurrentUnsecureUrl($request);

        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect($url)
            ->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }
}
```

then added this function

```
protected function _getCurrentUnsecureUrl($request)
{
    if ($alias = $request->getAlias(Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS)) {
        return Mage::getBaseUrl('link', false).ltrim($alias, '/');
    }

    return Mage::getBaseUrl('link', false).ltrim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
}
```